# Regular expression string division, priorize the part lengths

Tags: regex

I have this string

```
0Sc-a+nn1.ed_AI&amp;AO1301#89
```

That has to be split in three parts

```
0Sc-a+nn1.ed_AI&amp;AO

1301

89
```

I am using this RE `(?P<prefix>[a-z\.\_\-\+(\&amp;)]+\W?)(?P<num>((?P<ref_num>\d+)(#(?P<subpart_num>\d+))?))` in python, but for now, testing in https://regex101.com/.

I am having problem to identify the first part. If I try "Sc-a+nn.ed_AI&AO1301#89" works fine, but adding the numbers to the first part, as the example, don't.

How to priory the second and the third part to be the maximum length allowed around the `#` and the first one () allow numbers in the beginning and middle (never at the end because will be in part two)? `?` is there because sometimes the precedent element doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[a-zA-Z]{2}` to capture the string after `&amp;` and specify the length for each part i.e `[\d]{4}`

`(?P<prefix>[A-Za-z0-9._\-+&;]+[a-zA-Z]{2}?)(?P<num>((?P<ref_num>\d+)(#(?P<subpart_num>\d+))?))`

Comment: The problem is that even the length of each part is variable. The only rules are: number at the end are part of `<num>` (divided in `<ref_num>` and `<subpart_num>` by `#`), all the initial part (usually characters, but may have some number) are part of <preffix>. And also `<subpart_num>`  or `<num>` may not exist.

Comment: Tricky what will denote the end of the first group before any of the `<num>` subgroups having a length will help.

Comment: Understood, something that really will be  there. I used `(?P<prefix>[a-z\.\_\-\+(\&amp;)\d]+[a-z\.\_\-\+(\&amp;)])(?P<num>((?P<ref_num>\d+)(#(?P<subpart_num>\d+))?)?)`. I don't with is the best, but worked.